# Using route-href with child routers

Tags: javascript, aurelia

I'm attempting to use the `route-href` attribute inside a view in a child router. My parent router looks like so:

```
configureRouter(config, router){
    config.title = 'Kali';
    config.map([
        // { route: '', moduleId: 'no-selection', title: 'Select'},
        { route: ['', 'courses'],  moduleId: 'courses' }
    ]);

    this.router = router;
}
```

My child router looks like so:

```
configureRouter(config, router){
    config.map([
        { route: ['', '/'], moduleId: 'no-selection', title: 'Select'},
        { route: '/:id',  moduleId: 'courses/course-detail' }
    ]);

    this.router = router;
}
```

And here's my route-href attribute...

```
<a route-href="route: '', params: { id: course.id }" click.delegate="$parent.select(course.id)">
```

When I use this, I expect `route-href` to use the routes from the child router. Instead, I get this stacktrace. Looking through the code, I see that RouteHref calls `router.generate` to create the route. `router.generate` should walk up the router heirarchy recursively, so that shouldn't be a problem. I'm not sure, however, which router is being passed to the `route-href` constructor. I think there are two problems here - first, I'm not sure whether `route-href` is receiving the correct router, and second, I'm not sure if or how `route-href` handles an expression with an empty route.

Stack trace:

```
message: "There is no route named '', params: { id: course.id }"
stack: "Error: There is no route named '', params: { id: course.id }↵    at RouteRecognizer.generate (http://localhost:9000/jspm_packages/github/aurelia/route-recognizer@0.4.0/index.js:244:19)↵    at AppRouter.generate (http://localhost:9000/jspm_packages/github/aurelia/router@0.8.0/router.js:210:38)↵    at Router.generate (http://localhost:9000/jspm_packages/github/aurelia/router@0.8.0/router.js:207:32)↵    at RouteHref.processChange (http://localhost:9000/jspm_packages/github/aurelia/templating-router@0.12.0/route-href.js:42:34)↵    at RouteHref.bind (http://localhost:9000/jspm_packages/github/aurelia/templating-router@0.12.0/route-href.js:30:16)↵    at BehaviorInstance.bind (http://localhost:9000/jspm_packages/github/aurelia/templating@0.11.0/behavior-instance.js:68:35)↵    at View.bind (http://localhost:9000/jspm_packages/github/aurelia/templating@0.11.0/view.js:68:26)↵    at ViewFactory.create (http://localhost:9000/jspm_packages/github/aurelia/templating@0.11.0/view-factory.js:173:18)↵    at BoundViewFactory.create (http://localhost:9000/jspm_packages/github/aurelia/templating@0.11.0/view-factory.js:127:35)↵    at Repeat.processArrayItems (http://localhost:9000/jspm_packages/github/aurelia/templating-resources@0.11.0/repeat.js:132:32)"
```

Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: Did you try to use  the full route instead of the id alone ?

Comment: Also it does not look like it is processing your course.id ?

Comment: Yeah, I tried `route: courses, params: { id: course.id }` but that didn't work either. It did work before I introduced child routers.

Comment: This dont work at all

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It looks like `route-href` uses the `name` property of the route.

Perhaps your child router should look like this:

```
configureRouter(config, router){
    config.map([
        { route: ['', '/'], moduleId: 'no-selection', title: 'Select'},
        { route: '/:id',  moduleId: 'courses/course-detail', name: 'course-detail' }
    ]);

    this.router = router;
}
```

and in your view:

```
<a route-href="route: course-detail; params.bind: { id: course.id }" ...
```

Comment: No. `route-href` passes `this.route` to the `generate` method of router. `generate` does name its parameter "name", but that has nothing to do with it. I tried this, and it didn't work. Wish it had, though. Unfortunately, I'll probably just have to put together a test case for this.

Comment: I take this back, actually. I'm looking through this more and it looks like you might be correct - this still doesn't work, but it looks as though the route-recognizer module looks at `route.handler.name`, and the route configuration is passed in as the handler. I'm really not sure how this works, though.

Comment: Whoops! I just got this working on my machine. We were using a `,` in the `route-href` when we should have been using a `;` *facepalm*. I have edited the answer, it should work now.

Comment: Wow. That worked. I suppose I didn't expect a full JS expression inside the route-href handler - I neither expected the semicolon, nor the `params.bind` statement. Is there documentation for this? I'm willing contribute documentation on route-href usage, as I'm sure it'll help people who aren't yet familiar. I will say, it's a bit odd to see part of the binding language inside an expression like that. I wouldn't have expected it to have been parsed.

Comment: Additionally, the more I think about it....this worked with the original route, without any child routers involved. Wouldn't it be better to keep the behavior as uniform as possible? The `route-href` handler should probably access the underlying JS file for the view in which it resides, and then walk the parent chain from there (if necessary). This would enhance modularity and promote a uniform code standard regardless of the nested level.

Comment: The only place I have found any info on `route-href` is [the contacts app source](https://github.com/aurelia/app-contacts/blob/master/src/contact-list.html).

I'm not sure what you mean about a "uniform code standard regardless of the nested level", the syntax should be the same regardless of nested level. The route resolution will start at the current level and search upward until a match is found.

I'll also point out that the [Aurelia Gitter](https://gitter.im/Aurelia/Discuss) is really nice, there is usually a core team member in there, they could describe the routeing better than I.

Comment: What I know about route-href, I found in the contacts-app - if you can tell from my code, I actually used that project as a base. I'm well aware of the Gitter room - I was more active in the earlier stages of the project, but I haven't had the time lately. As for the uniform standard - `route-href` doesn't require a `name` property in the route config when you use it without child routers, as the app-contacts app shows. In my case, I can't use it without specifying a `name` property. I don't think that the code should have to change if you introduce child routers. Does that make sense?

Comment: I think I understand now. The `name` property is not exactly _required_ and that might be the source of confusion. If there is no `name` property on the route, it will try to match against a `title` property. You should be able to define child routes just like top level routes.

Comment: That's it exactly. i'll create an issue ticket in the github repository.

Comment: I find it absolutely appalling that a front-end web framework did not make clear the basic methods for adding an html link tag.